# "Whiz" and "wiz" in Wizard of Oz

Tags: meaning

In this famous song from The Wizard of Oz I do not completely understand the words *whiz* and *wiz*. I think it's probably a play on words.

What is the meaning of each use of *wiz* or *whiz*?

> We're off to see the Wizard
>
> The Wonderful Wizard of Oz
>
> We hear he is a **whiz** of a **wiz**
>
> If ever a **wiz** there was
>
> If ever, oh ever, a **wiz** there was
>
> The Wizard of Oz is one because
>
> Because, because, because, because, because
>
> Because of the wonderful things he does
>
> We're off to see the wizard
>
> The Wonderful Wizard of Oz!

Comment: "**each** word in **each** line? " ?! What **exactly** do you want to ask? :)

Comment: @Kris as "wiz" is said seveeral times I wasn't sure if the meaning was always the same

Comment: I believe for the lyrics to make sense (in the nominal way a silly song can do so) the second and third "wiz"s should be "whiz".  I believe the point of the lyric is that the Wizard of Oz should be considered an excellent example of a wizard, if such excellent examples are to be found.  As it is written by OP, it suggests that the Wizard of Oz should be considered an excellent example of a wizard, if there is such a thing as a wizard.  I believe the former interpretation is preferable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wiz is a short form for Wizard.

In the context above Whiz means:

> **Whiz**
>
> "clever person," 1914, probably a special use of whiz "something
>   remarkable" (1908), an extended sense of whizz; or perhaps a shortened
>   form of wizard. Noun phrase whiz kid is from 1930s, a take-off on a
>   radio show's quiz kid. - [Online Etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=whiz&searchmode=none)

Synonyms for Whiz

> ace, genius, virtuoso, prodigy, expert, clever

The Author is using the [homonymes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym) whiz and wiz to create a word play. He is saying that the Wizard in the Wizard of Oz is the smartest, cleverest Wizard that exists because of all the wonderful things he does.

The original meaning of Whiz:

> Whiz started out as [onomatopoeia](http://grammar.about.com/od/mo/g/onomaterms.htm) describing:
>
> 1. To make a whirring or hissing sound, as of an object speeding through air.
> 2. To move swiftly with or as if with such a sound; rush: whizzed past on a ten-speed

*thank you [Jay Elston](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/8737/jay-elston) for the last part*

I hope I could help ; )

Comment: *Whiz* started out as onomatopoeia, and was (and still is) applied to objects that move through the air, such as arrows or birds. Later, it was used to describe people who ran fast (he is a whiz at football). Finally one of its meanings evolved to describe remarkable people.

Comment: yes you are correct. Thank you for teaching me a new word. I didn't know what onomatopoeia was. ( I looked it up ; ) )

Answer (score 4):

*Wiz* is short for wizard. *Whiz* means something remarkable.

Comment: "Whiz" is someone who is "dazzlingly skilled" http://www.thefreedictionary.com/whiz

Answer (score 0):

'Whiz' and 'wiz' are variant spellings of the standard 'whizz'. 'Whiz' is more typical throughout North America and 'wiz' tends to be favoured when used alongside the related word 'wizard', which has a secondary definition identical to 'whizz'/'whiz'/'wiz': an extremely clever person. Thus 'a whizz of a whizz' is someone who is not only extremely clever but who is perceived to be extremely clever even amongst extremely clever people.

Comment: Technically you appear to be correct, but your answer could use some references.